# I need help to install nitroshare on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu

I am beginner in Ubuntu 20.04 and I need to share my files from my Windows to Ubuntu via Nitroshare.
With that I browses it and followed the instructions to download through terminal, while running the last command which is `sudo apt-get install nitroshare` it showed an error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nitroshare
```

the whole commands I used to install nitroshare is:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:george-edison55/nitrosharesudo
sudo ​apt-get update
​sudo apt-get install nitroshare
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To download Nitroshare from an [official 18.04 LTS Ubuntu repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nitroshare) and install it in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS run the following commands.

```
sudo apt update
cd ~/Downloads/
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nitroshare/nitroshare_0.3.3-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./nitroshare/nitroshare_0.3.3-1_amd64.deb
```